# Eclipse highlighting the same occurrence of the word

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, syntax-highlighting

In  Notepad++, it has a very nice feature that if I select a word, it will highlight all the same words throughout the text. I can also set the hot-keys to highlight up to five different  words with different styles (See the effect below) .

[image]

Is there any ways to get this similar effect in eclipse? I know when editing Java, it will highlight all the same variables, but it will not work when I highlight the comments and editing other files type (e.g. xml, html, js, css and etc).

Comment: [Similar question here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16727024) @KenChan Would be nice if you accepted winxton's answer :) The plugin does exactly what you want, and even gives a Chrome-like overview near the scroll bar (can be turned off in Annotations Preferences).

Comment: And [another duplicate here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12301080/983430). As @ADTC said, please accept winxton's answer (or let us know how it _doesn't_ meet your requirements - I'm pretty sure it does). I've marked both the others as possible duplicates of this one.

Comment: @KenChan, in the new Eclipse Oxygen it works natively! check my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/42007441/658497

Comment: Select the term and press ctrl + alt +g

Answer (score 35):

I've been working with Eclipse for quite a while and I'm pretty certain that there is no canonical way of doing this.

In Eclipse these things are managed on a per-editor basis and the Java editor does not support what your looking for for all I know. At least for the Java editor you can do some minor configuration in what is highlighted and how (`Preferences > Java > Editor > Mark Occurrences`), but I guess you already know that.

As for plugins, I'm not aware of any plugin that achieves what you're looking for. As a matter of fact I'd be surprised if there really was a plugin which achieves what you're looking for.

If something comes up I'd much appreciate you sharing it here, I've been trying to get decent highlighting into Eclipse for years unsuccessfully... :)

Answer (score 30):

Here is a plugin for eclipse: http://ystrot.github.io/glance/

It highlights all occurrences as with notepad++ upon hitting Ctrl + Alt + F.

Comment: Nice! If it had the replace window, I could replace the find/replace key binding with Glance's one.

Comment: Needs to be the accepted answer! It's exactly what the asker wants. Plain text highlighting, which is different from "mark occurrences" which highlights occurrences of selected entity (method, variable, constructor, etc).

Comment: Awesome! To achieve this effect alone I had to open files in "geany".

Comment: Not compatible with Eclipse Jee 2019-06

Answer (score 6):

Below is what I found works for me but you can also assign a key shortcut to 'Find Text in File':

1. Select the word or section of text
2. Press `CTR+3` to activate 'Quick Access' search
3. Type 'Find Text in File'
4. Execute

As mentioned by @Kislingk you can modify how the words are highlighted/marked in 'Preferences > General >Editors>Text Editors > Annotations'.

[image: eclipse-highlight-search-results-in-file]

Comment: Once we toggle this, how to revert back?

Comment: All that's left is add a key (e.g. Ctrl+Alt+S) shortcut to "Find Text in File" in "Preferences > General -> Keys"

Answer (score 5):

Here is the closest solution I have found:

1. Create a shortcut in Preferences/General/Keys
   type in the search field: "Find Text in File"
   By default it has nothing assigned so just assign your key binding to it.
2. Annotations can help with displaying it in the sidebar

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you enable "Mark Occurrences" (Alt + Shift + O), then all words that are the same as the one you have marked will be highlighted.

[image]

Comment: this button is enabled only when editing java files, but i need it for text files

Answer (score 1):

Well if you're searching in the currently open file only (via CTRL-F) then no, you can't have everything highlighted.

However if you use the advanced search (CTRL-H, then go to "File search" tab) there you can input the search pattern, as well as the file-name pattern for the file(s) where it should search, and when the search is done, the search terms are highlighted in each file where they were found:

[image]

Comment: the CTRL-H search works for any file. You also have a nice triaje in the (lower right) console (in the search tab) of each file and the occurence of your search terms in it. It's a little demanding (you have to press several keys and fill in two text fields) but in the end it does exactly what you asked.

Answer (score 1):

Use file search to search selected resource can highlight same word in single file.

Answer (score 1):

Another useful eclipse plugin is [eclipse instasearch](https://github.com/ajermakovics/eclipse-instasearch). It has extensive feature set. This is also available in eclipse marketplace.

Answer (score 0):

There are other options needed to enable.(Preferences > General >Editors>Text Editors > Annotations).  Find Occurrences and WriteOccurrences and enable Text as 'Hightlight'

Answer (score 0):

Have tried all of the above answer, but all not working. At the end, i found that it's due to i have accidentally remove some of the **JRE System Library**, after add back, it's work correctly

Answer (score 0):

Window > Preferences > Java > Editor > Mark Occurrences