# Highlight same words in text files in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, text, notepad++, highlight

Is there any option to highlight same words in text files in Eclipse. I know that eclipse is highlighting java code.

But can we also enable somehow highlighting of same words in text files?

The same function is in Notepad++. If we select some word it will highlight all the same words in the whole file.

[image: notepad++ highlight]