# Highlighting all occurrences of a search string in Eclipse Java editor

Tags: eclipse, ide, refactoring

If you search for a String in Netbeans Java editor, it automatically highlights all occurrences of that string.

But, how can I achieve this feature in Eclipse?

(I checked Preferences > Java > Editor > Mark Occurrences, but it seems it is only for similar variables methods etc. but not for for search matches)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eclipse highlighting the same occurrence of the word](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7238349/eclipse-highlighting-the-same-occurrence-of-the-word)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Have you tried the Glance [plugin](http://ystrot.github.io/glance/) for Eclipse? fully meet your requirements and even with more features.

demo and Github of this project:
http://ystrot.github.io/glance/

---

**UPDATE:** available in Eclipse marketplace

http://marketplace.eclipse.org/marketplace-client-intro?mpc_install=1012

Comment: This plugin is great but it is no longer actively maintained and not available for the latest Eclipse releases

Answer (score 8):

You can enable "Toggle Mark Occurrences" (shortkey is <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>).

For the color of the select text,you can:

> Window->Preferences->General->Editors->Text Editors->Annotations->Occurrences

Hope it useful.

Comment: Yes! This works in my Kepler version. There's also a tool button on toolbar.

Comment: Be sure 'Occurrance' and 'Write Occurrance' both have set Text in highlight checked so that when you highlight a word, the declaration and use of that variable will both be highlighted. Otherwise the 'declaraion' won't be highlighted.

Answer (score 4):

[eclipse instasearch plugin](https://github.com/ajermakovics/eclipse-instasearch) is a very useful plugin for search needs inside eclipse.
It is based on lucene. This is also available in eclipse marketplace.

It has extensive feature set.

- Instantly shows search results
- Shows a preview using relevant lines
- Periodically updates the index
- Matches partial words (e.g. case in CamelCase)
- Opens and highlights matches in files
- Searches JAR source attachments
- Supports filtering by extension/project/working set