# Highlighting curly brackets with a different colour in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, customization, syntax-highlighting

Eclipse highlights all brackets in Java source with the same colour, while I would like to highlight curly brackets with a different colour.

Here is what I mean:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: What does 'differentiate curly brackets.' mean?

Comment: @user It means that I want them to be highlighted with a different colour than other brackets (I have edited my question to clarify this).

Comment: Different colour in different nesting level?

Comment: @user No.  Same colour for all curly brackets.

Answer (score 5):

You can only change colour of 'matching brackets highlight' what you can find in :

`Preferences -> Java(or other) -> Editor -> Matching bracket highlight`

or all brackets and parentheses colour in:

`Preferences -> Java (or other) -> Editor -> Syntax Coloring -> Brackets`.

Comment: I would have guessed that there is a configuration file somewhere that says to Eclipse how to match brackets in Java. Isn't this the case?  Usually, text editors use configuration files for syntax highlighting.

Comment: @Elena The Java editor builds a complete [Abstract Syntax Tree](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJDT/article.html) of the Java so it does not need any separate configuration of how to match brackets.

Comment: @greg-449 Therefore how can I hook into this AST to customize the colour of curly brackets?  What Eclipse plugin should I modify?

Comment: Well the Java editor is in the org.eclipse.jdt.ui plugin - modifying this would be very hard work.

Comment: The "matching brackets highlight" is what I'm looking for. Finally!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Bracketeer](http://mcuoneclipse.com/2012/06/10/bracketeer-the-ultimate-bracket-plugin/) plugin which is very helpful one.

You can change the background and foreground colors in preference page. See below

[image]

- [Bracketeer for C/C++ (CDT)](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/bracketeer-cc-cdt)
- [Bracketeer for Java (JDT)](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/bracketeer-java-jdt)

---

### Looking after your comments...

Go to `Preferences -> Java (or other) -> Editor -> Syntax Coloring -> Brackets` and try to change the color of Brackets, then you can see all parenthesis, and curly brackets changes its colors in preview box below. That means its not possible to change the color of curly brackets **ONLY** in JDT editor.

> **So answer is its not possible to have different colors for curly brackets and parenthesis**.

### Any other workarounds:

1. Its not satisfactory but you can try glance and/or instasearch plugins. Check this post [Highlighting all occurrences of a search string in Eclipse Java editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16727024/highlighting-all-occurrences-of-a-search-string-in-eclipse-java-editor). These plugins will highlight all occurrences of a word but you want this **{** and this **}** at the same time to be highlighted.
2. Use Java search. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> then in use `[{}]+` as search key and enable **Regular expression** option. Depending on the scope you chosen all/selected files will highlight all curly braces[Untill next Java search or restart].

Comment: As far as I can see, this plugin doesn't solve my problem, that is: showing all curly brackets in the same colour, different from parentheses.  Am I missing something?

Comment: In the **Pairs to show** group disable parenthesis, square brackets and angle brackets and ONLY keep curly brackets enabled. If it is not what you expect, please edit your post and put some screen shots to understand your question more accurately.

Comment: OK, now I have understood how the plugin works and it is not what I am trying to accomplish. Brackeeter highlights brackets that surround the cursor, whilst I am trying to highlight curly brackets no matter where the cursor is (I have added a screenshot).  Thanks anyway for your suggestion.